# How to declare a hashmap with type <&str, String> in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'd like to declare a `HashMap` member in my structure, and as the keys will be always a static literals and the content shall be modified, so the type I expected is:

```
pub struct SmpStruct {
    word_dict: HashMap<&str, String>,
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler gives me the feedback:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |     word_dict: HashMap<&str, String>,
  |                        ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

As an alternative, I'm using `HashMap<String, String>`:

```
pub struct SmpStruct {
    word_dict: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

This solution works, but is not perfect. Can anyone explain what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify that the lifetime of the keys is `'static`:

```
pub struct SmpStruct {
    word_dict: HashMap<&'static str, String>,
}
```

In struct fields or enum variants, [lifetime parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#in-structs) cannot be omitted; they must be specified explicitly, and if you want to accept lifetimes other than `'static`, then you must add a lifetime parameter on the struct or enum itself.